# Can't play godot game as a software in pc

Tags: export, desktop, godot

I made a game in Godot and exported it in release mode in Desktop as exe file.

But, it also created a .pck file and a highscore.data file.

I want to create it as an installable application and I don't want the highscore file in front.

What can I do? I also want to publish it.

I am new in Godot and this is my first game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installers are usually wrappers, aside applications that extract the main app to specific directory. Godot doesn't provide functions to create one. If you really need installer, you can write one or just generate with tools like NSIS, Inno Setup and others...

Separate `.pck` file can be embeded by enabling "Embed Pck" option in export settings.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zzgq.png)

I'm not sure what `highscore.data` file is, but it looks like something creating from code. Use `user://` prefix (like `user://highscore.data`) for file paths to create them in app_userdata directory (more in [docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/data_paths.html#user-path-persistent-data)).

So if you use this two options, you will get a single `.exe` file with game.